# Constant crashes from ubuntu 12.10 amd

Tags: 12.10

I am getting constant crashes whenever I try to install, use, view video, firefox, compiz etc from Ubuntu 12.10 amd, or 12.04.02.

System:

AMD 64bit Athlon, x2 core
Geforce 7900 GS 512MB DDR3 Standard
Memory: Teamelite DDR II, 800Mhz 2X1GB
M/B: ASRock ALIVE Dual eSata II

What could be the problem?

BR

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  This appears to be either a hardware problem, in which case we can not help you, or a bug, in which case you should report it on [Ubuntu's Launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. I reinstalled Ubuntu and it worked perfectly after the reinstallation. You should do a back-up of your system after reinstall so you can reset if something goes wrong again.

Comment: No its not like that.

I have made about 12 re-installations...

Something else is systematically wrong here...